# Scrapping Dynamic Table Using Selenium WebDriver Wait Returning Truncated Data Frame

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, webdriverwait, dynamic-tables

I try to scrap a dynamic table called "holding"
from https://www.ishares.com/us/products/268752/ishares-global-reit-etf

At first I use selenium but I got empty DataFrame. Then community here helps suggest me to induce "WebDriverWait" to fully load the data before extracting it. It works but the data I got is truncated from 400 rows down to only 10 rows. How can I get all the data I need. Anyone could help me please. Thank you.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd

# Instantiate options
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.headless = True

# Instantiate a webdriver
site = 'https://www.ishares.com/us/products/268752/ishares-global-reit-etf'
wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver', options=options)
wd.get(site)

# Induce WebDriver Wait
WebDriverWait(wd, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click()
wd.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", WebDriverWait(wd, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@data-componentname]/h2[normalize-space()='Holdings']"))))
data = WebDriverWait(wd, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@aria-describedby='allHoldingsTable_info']"))).get_attribute("outerHTML")
data2  = pd.read_html(data)
holding = data2[0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you wrote is ok, but you missed one point. The table as a default is designed with pagination, which shows only 10 records per page, and hence you retrieved only those records. You have to add an additional action step (clicking on 'Show More' button) which would show all records, and thus your df would have all of them. Here is the refactored code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import pandas as pd
import time

# Instantiate options
opt = Options()
opt.add_argument("headless")
opt.add_argument("disable-gpu")
opt.add_argument("window-size=1920,1080")

# Instantiate a webdriver
site = 'https://www.ishares.com/us/products/268752/ishares-global-reit-etf'
wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver', options=opt)
wd.maximize_window()
wd.get(site)

# Induce WebDriver Wait
WebDriverWait(wd, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click()
wd.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", WebDriverWait(wd, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@data-componentname]/h2[normalize-space()='Holdings']"))))
WebDriverWait(wd, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//*[@class='datatables-utilities ui-helper-clearfix']//*[text()='Show More'])[2]"))).click()
data = WebDriverWait(wd, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@aria-describedby='allHoldingsTable_info']"))).get_attribute("outerHTML")
data2  = pd.read_html(data)
holding = data2[0]
print(holding)
```

Output:

```
    Ticker                           Name  ...    SEDOL Accrual Date
0      PLD              PROLOGIS REIT INC  ...  B44WZD7            -
1     EQIX               EQUINIX REIT INC  ...  BVLZX12            -
2      PSA            PUBLIC STORAGE REIT  ...  2852533            -
3      SPG  SIMON PROPERTY GROUP REIT INC  ...  2812452            -
4      DLR  DIGITAL REALTY TRUST REIT INC  ...  B03GQS4            -
..     ...                            ...  ...      ...          ...
379    MYR                        MYR/USD  ...        -            -
380    MYR                        MYR/USD  ...        -            -
381    MYR                        MYR/USD  ...        -            -
382    MYR                        MYR/USD  ...        -            -
383    MYR                        MYR/USD  ...        -            -

[384 rows x 12 columns]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice. But I still got error message that I couldn't understand what is the problem as below; ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element <a href="#" class="toggle-records" role="button">...</a> is not clickable at point (737, 566). Other element would receive the click: <a href="#" class="back-to-top" aria-hidden="true" title="Back to Top" style="display: inline;">...</a>
  (Session info: headless chrome=97.0.4692.71)

Comment: Which element is it that you are getting error on? Have you tried to locate the line of code on which the error is occurring? If yes, post it here, and I shall try to look into it when I am free.

Comment: Really appreciate it, Thank you. It got the error message when I run WebDriverWait(wd, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//*[@class='datatables-utilities ui-helper-clearfix']//*[text()='Show More'])[2]"))).click()

Comment: I only have chromedriver saved in my directory, do I need some other application or package installed to make this "show more record" step works?

Comment: @Mango, after some investigation, I found that the code fails in only headless mode. Then I discovered that adding window-size to the chromeoptions agrument made sense and it worked. I have updated the refactored code in my answer. Please check. I tested the refactored code, and now the records are fetched even in headless mode

Comment: wow, this works now, Thank you so much. I have spent a lot of time on this problem. Thank you Thank you. =)